# Cell referencing in Openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

If I reference the value of a cell:

```
A1_value = ws['A1'].value
```

Is there a easy to reference cell A2, or B2 without having to retype out for example:

```
 A2_value = ws['A2'].value
```

Thanks!

Comment: Strange question. What is your goal?

Answer (score 4):

You can access cells programmatically using `ws.cell(row, column)`. But cells also have an `.offset(row, column)` method for obtaining nearby cells.